# Is it possible to embed external .exe in html?

Tags: python, rest, web

As question implies, is it possible to run for eg: calc.exe in browser? like embed src=calc.exe or something?

Your help/suggestions will be appreciated.

The actual application created with python.

Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not possible. What would it even mean if the client isn't running the proper OS?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  You can *link to* a file, not sure what "embedding an .exe" is intended to do or even look like.  And the file you link to has to be accessible by the user of course.  And links to .exe files are obviously going to be pretty high on anybody's "potential virus, don't allow it" scale.  Not to mention it would be meaningless to anybody not running Windows.  Ultimately it sounds like what you're describing is something of an XY Problem.  Whatever solution you're trying to implement is wrong, but we don't know what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: the .exe is image processing tool. Basically want to migrate the python program to cloud.

Comment: @Cowarrior: *"Basically want to migrate the python program to cloud."* - Well, we don't know anything about your Python program.  But if you're expecting web browsers to happily execute any .exe you link to on the internet then think again.  It may indeed be possible to port your Python code to a web application, or it is certainly possible to create a web application which uses an external .exe server-side.  There's potentially a variety of approaches you can take.  But at this point that's all entirely too broad to be meaningfully answered here.

Comment: @David Thanks. Python program is a PyQT GUI application which uses MySQL DB. Right now, a click event in the GUI triggers execution of another process(Image view) in the PyQT GUI itself (within application) where user can interact with the images and fetches information about cursor position etc. My job is to make that task possible through use of cloud technology. Making web service from scratch isnt feasible since it has tons of lines. Deploying to docker is another, but heard that GUI isn't supported. So really dont know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your file downloadable, but you can't make a executable file run directly via a web browser.

But if the program is already installed on the client's machine and you want to invoke that program from browser this is possible.
For example : if you are not able to find how to update your windows then just go to windows update page and you will get a button when you press button, windows update settings just gets opened.

Visit for more help on how to open a software using browser in windows : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)